# Attempt to print all records in a table only get's the first 16 rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

When I run the below Python program the statement

```
print([
    my_elem.text for my_elem in
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
        .until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
             (By.XPATH,
                 "/html/body/div[1]/ui-view/div/div[1]"
                 "/div/div/div/div/exploration-container/exploration-container-modern"
                 "/div/div/exploration-host/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas-modern"
                 "/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container-modern[9]/transform"
                 "/div/div[3]/detail-visual-modern/div/visual-modern/div/div/div[2]/div[1]"
             )
         ))
])
```

should print all records in the table but it only prints the first 16 rows plus 4 rows from the second column. How can I get all rows printed?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiZGYxNjYzNmUtOTlmZS00ODAxLWE1YTEtMjA0NjZhMzlmN2JmIiwidCI6IjljOWEzMGRlLWQ4ZDctNGFhNC05NjAwLTRiZTc2MjVmZjZjNSIsImMiOjh9")
for i in range(1, 4):
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='navigation-wrapper navigation-wrapper-big']//i[@title='Next Page']"))).click()

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/ui-view/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/exploration-container/exploration-container-modern/div/div/exploration-host/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas-modern/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container-modern[9]/transform")).perform()
action.context_click().perform()
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@title='Show as a table']")))
action.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/ui-view/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/exploration-container/exploration-container-modern/div/div/exploration-host/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas-modern/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container-modern[9]/transform/div/div[3]/detail-visual-modern/div/visual-modern/div/div/div[2]/div[1]")))])
driver.quit()
```

**Additional info**

I managed to get this working although it feels a little hacky. Here's my latest code. You'll see there's a second `ActionChain`:

```py
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiZGYxNjYzNmUtOTlmZS00ODAxLWE1YTEtMjA0NjZhMzlmN2JmIiwidCI6IjljOWEzMGRlLWQ4ZDctNGFhNC05NjAwLTRiZTc2MjVmZjZjNSIsImMiOjh9")
    for i in range(1, 4):
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[@title='Next Page']"))).click()

    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/ui-view/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/exploration-container/exploration-container-modern/div/div/exploration-host/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas-modern/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container-modern[9]/transform")).perform()
    action.context_click().perform()
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@title='Show as a table']")))
    action.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
    action2 = ActionChains(driver)
    scroll_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/ui-view/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/exploration-container/exploration-container-modern/div/div/exploration-host/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas-modern/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container-modern[9]/transform/div/div[3]/detail-visual-modern/div/visual-modern/div")))
    action2.move_to_element(scroll_element).click()
    action2.send_keys(Keys.UP)
    action2.send_keys(Keys.UP)
    action2.send_keys(Keys.UP).perform()
    print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/ui-view/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/exploration-container/exploration-container-modern/div/div/exploration-host/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas-modern/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container-modern[9]/transform/div/div[3]/detail-visual-modern/div/visual-modern/div/div/div[2]/div[1]")))])
```

Can this be done with just one `ActionChain` and if so how?

Comment: The DOM could still be updating.  You can check that by catching any Stale Element exceptions when performing an action on an item (element reference) in the returned list.  (when checking presence of all elements, the list will return if at least 1 item is present.)

Comment: Are all the rows actually displayed when you run this statement? In addition to the possibility of the DOM still being built as part of the page initialization scripts, it could be that some of the content is not loaded, and waits until some event like a screen scroll.

Comment: Ah yes, it seems to be the scroll. This is the down arrow: `/html/body/div[1]/ui-view/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/exploration-container/exploration-container-modern/div/div/exploration-host/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas-modern/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container-modern[9]/transform/div/div[3]/detail-visual-modern/div/visual-modern/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]`. Can I use that to scroll to the bottom then run my print? If so, how would that be done?